# Graph with nodes on Android

Tags: android, graph

Is it possible to create/draw a graph with nodes and edges and show it in Android?
Something like this

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [webmathematics.net](http://webmathematics.net/images/six%20nodes.jpg))</sub>

Comment: (I suppose you're looking for that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android)

Comment: i am also looking for same...
@Sword22 ,none of them helps in network graph I think.
If yes than please give some guidance

Comment: @SakPonte Can you tell us which technique/library you ended up using?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this class.

[SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)

Also you can use OpenGL in Android, if you're familiar with it. Good luck!

Comment: is there a lib that makes a dynamically and cool looking graph?